# update svelte reference when a prop change

Tags: html, svg, svelte

I created an svg `text` and I need to create a responsive `rect`angle outside the `text` using a `svg` (no `div`).

Since the `text` lenght may change based on window size, also the `rect` width should change.

[Here a working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/60170ee8f1e2421697ec47671650061f?version=3.55.0) and below my code:

`App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import Wrapper from './Wrapper.svelte'
    
    let w = 0
    $: h = Math.min(w, 300)
    
    function getTileLabel(w) {
    if (w < 200) {
      return (d) => d.name
    }
    return (d) => `Long label ${d.name}`
  }
    
    const data = [{name: 'a', y: 0}, {name: 'bbbbb', y: 50}, {name: 'ccc', y: 100}]
    $: getLabel = getTileLabel(w)
</script>

<div bind:clientWidth={w}>
    <Wrapper
        w={w}
        h={h}
        {data}
        {getLabel}
    />
</div>
```

`Wrapper.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import Container from './Container.svelte'
    
  export let w
    export let h
  export let data
  export let getLabel
</script>

<svg x={0} y={0} width={w} height={h}>
  {#each data as d}
    <Container {d} label={getLabel(d)} />
  {/each}
</svg>

<style>
    svg {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

`Container.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    export let d
  export let label

  let textElement

  $: textElementBB = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect()

  $: x0 = 0
  $: y0 = d.y
  $: width = d.width
  $: height = d.height
  $: borderWidth = textElementBB?.width
  $: borderHeight = textElementBB?.height
  $: borderX = x0 
  $: borderY = y0 
  $: textX = borderX
  $: textY = borderY
</script>

<rect x={borderX} y={borderY} width={borderWidth} height={borderHeight} stroke="tomato" stroke-width={2} fill="none" />
<text
            bind:this={textElement}
            fill="black"
            x={textX}
            y={textY}
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
            >
    {label}
</text>
```

The `text` becomes smaller if you resize the window but the `rect` width does not change. Why?
I think the problem is because the reference of the `text` node does not change when `label` change.

So I think the problem is here:

```html
  let textElement
```

am I right? How can I solve? Is there something like an `useEffect` of React for Svelte?

Answer (score 3):

Reactivity is based on assignments and events (when using bindings). Here you are only referencing the element which is not reassigned.

There are two options I can think of, both of which drop the use of `getBoundingClientRect`:

- Directly use bindings for [`clientWidth` and `clientHeight`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property-block-level-element-bindings) on the element
- Add a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) that observes the element and update the values in its callback

Answer (score 1):

A useEffect-ish function would look something like

```
<script>

  let borderWidth = 0
  let borderHeight = 0
  let textElement
     
  $: {
    // EVERY line within the object will execute when ANY variable within the object changes. In this case, textElement will change and this object will execute.         

    borderWidth = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
    borderHeight = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().height
  }

</script>
```

The React version of this would be

```
let borderWidth = 0
let borderHeight = 0
let textElement

useEffect(() => {

  borderWidth = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
  borderHeight = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().height

}, [borderWidth, borderHeight, textElement]
```

One step further, let's say you only wanted to react when textElement changed and NOT when borderWidth or borderHeight change. For that you would declare a function outside of the object and call it from with the object.

```
<script>

  let borderWidth = 0
  let borderHeight = 0
  let textElement

  const updateBorderDims = () => {
     borderWidth = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
     borderHeight = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect().height
  }
     
  $: {
     // do something to get the dependancy within the object, here I'm declaring another variable t - this variable isn't passed        
     let t = [textElement]

     updateBorderDims()
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in Svelte the `bind:this` is a DOM binding, not a state binding so it won't be reactive. You could use Svelte's `afterUpdate()` lifecycle function to update watch for DOM changes, but I feel that the Svelte way of doing it would be binding the window size to variables and running a reactive declaration that reads the bind:this object to update the variable whenever the window size changes, like this:

```
<svelte:window bind:innerHeight={vh} bind:innerWidth={vw}/>
<script>

  export let d
  export let label

  let vh, vw, //declaring variables that will bind to <svelte:window>'s height and width, respectively
      textElement,
      textElementBB, borderWidth, borderHeight; //should be declared here since you can't use a reactive declaration anymore
  
  // $: textElementBB = textElement && textElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  // $: borderWidth = textElementBB?.width
  // $: borderHeight = textElementBB?.height
  // become:

  $: if (vh || vw) {// whenever the value of vh or vw changes they will return a true bool value that will trigger the following logic
         textElementBB = textElement.getBBox(); //for some reason, getBoundingClientRect() doesn't scale properly while getBBox() does
         borderHeight = textElementBB.height;
         borderWidth = textElementBB.width;
         console.log(borderHeight + " x " + borderHeight)// just so you can see the values updating and compare with the dev tools reading.
     }

  $: x0 = 0
  $: y0 = d.y
  $: width = d.width
  $: height = d.height
  $: borderX = x0 
  $: borderY = y0 
  $: textX = borderX
  $: textY = borderY
</script>

<rect x={borderX} y={borderY} width={borderWidth} height={borderHeight} stroke="tomato" stroke-width={2} fill="none" />
<text
            bind:this={textElement}
            fill="black"
            x={textX}
            y={textY}
            alignment-baseline="hanging"
            >
    {label}
</text>
```

Since your focus is that the text lenght may change based on `window` size, I attached the reactivity to the svelte:window special element, but I feel that the reactive statement `$: if(condition) {do something}` is a great way of triggering Web APIs. I saw similar issues using the afterUpdate() function as solutions but I hit a bunch of edge cases where it just wasn't listening to DOM changes.

I hope this works, or at least pushes you in the right direction! Cheers!!